# Custom email domain with a third-party provider: security holes to watch out for?

Tags: email, domain

If I'm switching to `user@example.com` emails and using a third-party email service provider that I trust (for example, Google Apps), what potential security threats do I need to secure my system against?

Note that I am **not** referring to security threats pertaining to the email provider here (e.g. so I'm **not** talking about my Google Account's password or 2-factor authentication here).

Rather, I'm talking about the parts of the system that come **before** that.

For example, one thing I can think of is locking my domain name so it can't be transferred (ClientTransferProhibited), although that's pretty general, and not specifically email related.
What else do I need to guard against?

Answer (score 0):

one security threat is about content, and you can use PGP for encrypting your email, PGP is end-to-end and if you use a strong key your email provider can't decrypt your emails in reasonable time and cost.